# Does it possible to mention my page with graph api user feed share

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to share a post in my app on behalf of the user, and include mention to my facebook page in the post.
for that I'm trying to use Graph api with:
me/feed
while I have some message in the 'message' field, and I put my fb page id in the 'place' field, according to [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed):

place - "Page ID of a location associated with this post. Either link, place, or message must be supplied."

unfortunately, although I'm bot admin of the page I want to mention and the app I'm trying to do graph api request with, mention of my page not appearing.

any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got it, there is no way currently to achieve that via Graph API, mention page can be done only with page posts, the location field here is for page of LOCATION (meaning some place, and not any page)